# How to pipe stderr while leaving stdout alone in ksh?

Tags: pipe, ksh, stderr

I'm using `pax` to backup a directory over a `ssh` link. If like to have a progress report saying how much of the transfer has occurred. With the `-v` option, it'll output the filename that it's done to `stderr`, so I figured I could get the count of how many files are in the directory and somehow pipe `stderr` into my shell script and report how far it's gotten.

Thing is I'm not sure how to pipe `stderr` without disrupting `stdout`.  It's running `ksh` on the remote machine.

So this is what I have so far which will be run on the remote machine:

```sh
file_count=$(find "$target" -type f | wc -l)
count=0
progress() {
  while [ $((++count)) -lt $file_count ]; do
    echo -n "$((count * 100 / file_count))%\r" 1>&2
    read
  done
  echo 100% 1>&2
}

# This line needs to be modified somehow so that
# stderr goes to progress while leaving stdout
# alone.
echo "$target" | pax -r -v | progress
```

Seems that even though `read` says it supports `-n`, it doesn't, so I can't read from a particular handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to do this sort of thing in a Bourne shell is to temporarily redirect stdout to an auxiliary file descriptor.  Something like:

```
{ cmd 2>&1 1>&3 | progress; } 3>&1
```

Here, the stdout of `cmd` goes to the original stdout, while the stderr of `cmd` goes to `progress`. In your case, you should write:

```
{ echo "$target" | pax -r -v 2>&1 1>&3 | progress; } 3>&1
```

Note that any errors from `echo` will not go into the pipe to `progress` (which is probably fine, and probably what you want), and you may need to be concerned with buffering issues.  Also note the double quotes on `$target`.  For robustness, you should probably use `printf '%s\n' "$target"` rather than `echo`.

Comment: How do you mean I should be considered with buffeting issues?

Comment: Oh, and why should using `printf` be more robust than `echo`?

Comment: If `"$target"` expands to `-e`, then `echo "$target"` will print either a single newline or the string `-e`, depending on which implementation of `echo` is being used, but the behavior of `printf` is standardized.  There are other edge cases as well.  It *may* not matter if you know the structure of `$target`, but it's safer if you don't have to think about it.

Comment: Good to know.  And the buffering issue?

Comment: is there a way (in general) to use this in a process substation context rather than a pipe context?

Comment: @Adrian  yes, eg `{ a=$(cmd 2>&1 >&3); } 3>&1`  will assign the content that `cmd` writes to stderr to `a`, while the stdout of `cmd` will go to the original stdout.  This is a little bit sloppy, since with this construction `cmd` will execute with fd 3 open, which probably is not an issue, but you can clean it up with: `{ a=$(cmd 2>&1 >&3 3<&- ); } 3>&1`